# WebSocket and/or Request-Response

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, websocket

I'm creating a chat application, and one detail is that "acknowledgements" are crucial. I'll get to what that means. I'm trying to figure out what the best exchange protocol would be.

Scenario:
Alice sends Bob a message. Bob is offline, so the message is stored on the server. Bob connects to the server through a WebSocket connection. The server sends him messages that have been sent to him while he was away. This is where the problem arises. The WS API that's available for my app's ecosystem (Node.js, Nest.js specifically), has no pattern where it can wait for this message to be sent. The [mechanism](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/lib/websocket.js#L438) there seems to just be fire & forget. What if the payload is quite large and the connection drops while the message is being sent?

Now, I know socket.io has [support for acknowledgements](https://socket.io/docs/v4/emitting-events/#acknowledgements). But from what I've read, socket.io has some overhead and therefore less performance than optimal. Now whether that performance is something that I arguably need is another question, but I'm just trying to figure out how I can guarantee that the message has arrived on the other end. This means client-server and server-client directions. How can I `await` it? I know that one approach is to attach a unique ID to the socket event, and have the other side send you a confirmation that it received it. This is how socket.io does it if I'm not mistaken.
But my question there is how can I guarantee that the acknowledgement message was successfully sent? So then I'd need an "ack" for my "ack" and so on, so I'll always need one more acknowledgement so I don't know how that works.

What I though of as options is to use two REST endpoints to `send` and `receive` (or download) messages. You send when you send, but you receive when you receive a ping that there's messages for you to download. Now this could be done through a WebSocket connection where the server notifies the client about a new message and then the client can call this `receive` endpoint. This ping can also be done through a more managed solution like [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). The pros with that approach are twofold:

1. First, I have the REST interface to use, which is a lot more practical
2. I have the Request-Response pattern to use, so I have a theoretical guarantee that things are arriving if I get a response

Now the problem with this approach is that there's a lot of overhead from opening a new HTTP connection every time I want to send or receive messages, if I'm not mistaken:

3. I have to wait for the initial request time to get to the server before I actually have to wait for the server to respond with messages. With the pure WebSockets case, I would theoretically then just wait for the response equivalent part there (?)
4. This wastes bandwidth as well.

So one more question, where can I find out which clients will actually re-use an existing HTTP connection like a WebSocket connection, if available and not create a new one? Do all clients do that? Is it only the browser? What about apps? Is it on the OS level?

So the final question is how do I solve this problem of "acknowledgements" and not waste time and bandwidth? Are any of my conclusion/questions wrong or uninformed, am I missing something?

Notes:

1. server is Node.js and client is Flutter
2. i know about the WAMP subprotocol, but for my ecosystem it doesn't have very reliable implementations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact requirements or performance need,
but I did a project that also need reliable communication between client and server using websocket, the simplest I could think of was build `request-response` mechanism on top of websocket, and then build your application data on top of that.

here's high level overview how I implemented it:

implement request-response message using transaction to identify which response belongs to which request.

clients will have map storing transaction, when you send the message request wait for server to send a message response with the same transaction or wait
until timeout.

1. client wants to send message to server and construct the request as follow

```
{
  "event": "sendMessage",
  "type": "request",
  "transaction": "<uuid/unique-value>",
  "data": "<your-application-data>"
}
```

2. server parse the message and check that its a request with an event name `sendMessage` then call related function
3. server sends back response message to client

```
{
  "event": "sendMessage",
  "type": "response",
  "transaction": "<uuid/unique-value>", // same unique value as in request
  "data": "<your-application-data-result>"
}
```

4. because client has mapping which transaction belongs to which request, it is possible to match which request this response belongs to, if matched then complete the transaction